# In CUDA / Thrust, how can I access a vector element's neighbor during a for-each operation?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am trying to do some scientific simulation using Thrust library in CUDA, but I got stuck in the following operation which is basically a for-each loop:

```
device_vector<float> In(N);

for-each In(x) in In
      Out(x) = some_calculation(In(x-1),In(x),In(x+1));
end
```

I have already looked up stackoverflow.com and find some similar questions:
[Similar questions 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616066/thrust-vector-transformation-involving-neighbor-elements)

But it seems using a transform iterator is only possible when the some_calculation function is done between 2 parameters, for transform iterator passes two parameters at most.

Then, for question 2:
[Similar questions 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727225/thrust-accessing-neighbors)

The discussion just ended without a conclusion.

I believe this is a simple problem because it's a natural requirements for parallel calculation. Anyone could tell me what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fancy iterators are the key to this sort of operation, which isn't all that intuitive in thrust. You can use the `zip_iterator` to create tuples of values which can then be iterated over, so for a typical `f(x[i-1], x[i], x[i+1])` type function, you get something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>

struct divided_diff {
    float dx;
    divided_diff(float _dx) : dx(_dx) {};

    float operator()(const thrust::tuple<float, float, float> &in) const {
        float y0 = in.get<0>();
        float y1 = in.get<1>();
        float y2 = in.get<2>();

        return (y0 - 2.f * y1 + y2) / (dx * dx);
    }
};

int main() {
    const int N = 10;
    const float dx = 0.1f;
    float x[N], y[N], dydx[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        x[i] = dx * float(i);
        y[i] = std::sin(x[i]);
        dydx[i] = 0.f;
    }

    auto begin = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(&y[0], &y[1], &y[2]));
    auto end = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(&y[N-2], &y[N-1], &y[N]));

    divided_diff f(dx);
    thrust::transform(begin, end, &dydx[1], f);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << " " << dydx[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here the functor processes one tuple at a time, where the tuple contains the three inputs from three different starting points in the same array or iterative sequence.

---

EDIT: Apparently converting a host version of this code to use device constructs was proving challenging for the originally poster, so here is a version which executes everything on the device using `thrust::device_vector` as the base container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

struct divided_diff {
    float dx;
    divided_diff(float _dx) : dx(_dx) {};

    __device__
    float operator()(const thrust::tuple<float, float, float> &in) {
        float y0 = in.get<0>();
        float y1 = in.get<1>();
        float y2 = in.get<2>();

        return (y0 - 2.f*y1 + y2) / (dx * dx);
    }
};

struct mysinf {
    __device__
    float operator()(const float &x) { 
        return __sinf(x); 
    }
};

int main()
{

    const int N = 10;
    const float dx = 0.1f;
    thrust::device_vector<float> x(N), y(N), dydx(N-2);

    thrust::sequence(x.begin(), x.end(), 0.f, dx); 
    thrust::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), mysinf());

    auto start  = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(y.begin(), y.begin()+1, y.begin()+2));
    auto finish = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(y.end()-2, y.end()-1, y.end()));

    divided_diff f(dx);
    thrust::transform( start, finish, dydx.begin(), f);

    thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator it = dydx.begin();
    for(; it != dydx.end(); ++it) {
        float val = *it;
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there any advantage / disadvantage compared to storing the pointer in the functor and just passing the index to the functor?

Comment: In this simple case, probably not. But by using iterators, this could be extended to much more  complex cases where each iterator within the zipped tuple abstracts a non trivial ordering.

Comment: But when I tried to use you code on thrust::device_vector, it turned out a "thrust::system::system_error " error .   
What I did was to replace x[N], y[N], dxdy[N] by thrust::device_vector, and replace "make_tuple" statement by "make_tuple(x.begin(),x.begin() +1,x.begin() +2)".     
Would you tell me is it possible to realize implement your code based on vectors?

Comment: @WesleyRanger: Yes it is possible

Comment: @talonmies I did it, thank you ! Finally , I found out that my code thrown that exception because I used a thrust::generate function on a device_vector  ::>_<::